# Do you get the gist of this little text?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-play

It is on T.S.A. account on Instagram:

"Allow us to deliver some flamin’ hot tips that should catapult you to success. It’s not a flight of passage to bring the most obvious prohibited item in your bag. This bazooka was found yesterday morning by our threat eliminator officers at Raleigh-Durham International Airport (RDU)."

the context:

"https://www.instagram.com/p/CY7AVyaPVrF/?utm_source=ig_embed&ig_rid=c7ed135c-e26c-4baf-a094-5819dcd1edfc"

still i don't get the joke, what is a "flight of passage"??

"It’s not a flight of passage to bring the most obvious prohibited item in your bag."

does any body here get this?

Comment: Possibly a mishearing of 'rite of passage' (a significant event or achievement in someone's life). Don't expect good (or even coherent) English from Instagram.

Comment: Also a parody of "right of passage". I guess the author was pleased with their (perhaps 'off-the-cuff') phrase.

Comment: Or mixed metaphors – "Rite of passage" and "Flight of fancy".

Comment: Summary: written by a bozo, maybe on a phone, in a hurry.

Comment: Of course, the other obvious observation: This was at an airport, where people board *flights*. (I'm a bit terrified that it's the airport a few miles from me!) Also note, some Disney theme parks have a ride called "Flight of Passage"; subconscious awareness of this might have prompted the author.

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph shows several attempts at punning that perhaps reach so far that they lose their intent. In this case, the primary meaning is the idiom "rite of passage." The author also used "flamin'" and "catapult" in the previous sentence to humorously(?) suggest fiery projectiles. Changing "rite" to "flight" might continue the same theme, by suggesting the "flight" of a grenade, or it might allude to the airport and the act of commercial "flight."

A less strained paraphrase of the opening sentences might be:

> Here are some tips that can help you. It's not an accomplishment or honor to bring the most obvious prohibited item...